# File being published to wrong location or not at all in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017, swagger

**Background**

So I have two computers I'm developing on. I call them Surface and Asus. On the Surface it works fine to publish and on the Asus the file won't come along. The Asus computer have the latest version of VS2017 15.5.3 and it was when updating to 15.5.2 it stopped working. The Surface have 15.4.2. Now I'm not sure if it has anything to do with the Visual Studio version but that is the only thing different between them. I completely removed the solution from the Asus and git init/fetch to get it back up again. 
**Update** Don't think it has to do with VS. Publishing from the Surface with release to the production slot gives the exact same error as publishing to staging slot from Asus machine.

**The problem**

Publishing to Azure App Service don't include APIFront.xml file when attempting it on the Asus machine. Also, in the bin folder there are Any CPU and Debug folders while the Surface have Release and Debug folders.

If I include the file in project and "Copy always" it will be added to path descibed in image below. When app service is starting it can't because
"An error occurred while starting the application.
FileNotFoundException: Could not find file 'D:\home\site\wwwroot\APIFront.xml'."

[image]

The application is a .Net core 2.0 app which should run as a web api with swagger. It is just a PoC really but I still need to get it to work.

Comment: Do you have the code hosted on GitHub? Maybe I can try it for you, see if I get the same error?

Comment: Is that `APIFront.xml` an XML documentation file?

Comment: @HelderSepu Yes, it is.

Answer (score 1):

On your project properties check the build options, sounds like your XML documentation is only been created for the Debug configuration it should be on both.

[image]

You can also check the .csproj file, here is an example:

```
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <Optimize>false</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE;HAVE_MEMORY_BARRIER</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
    <DocumentationFile>XmlComments.XML</DocumentationFile>
    <NoWarn>1591</NoWarn>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE;HAVE_MEMORY_BARRIER</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

You can see that the DocumentationFile is only on one when it should be on both.